# what will remain of scope of a function after it has been called?

Tags: javascript, closures

i was working with closures and i came to this code:

```
doit = true;
aww = function() {
    if(doit) {var foo; doit = false;} else {}
    foo = 0; foo += 1; return foo;
}
```

`doit` is a variable that `aww` function uses to only define/delcare `foo` once.
when i execute `aww` for first time, it delcares `foo` as a local variable (and set to not declare it on future calls) then it assigns `foo` to 0 and increases it by 1. and returns it (1)

I expect that, next time i call `aww` the `foo` variable is not declared first, so that the `aww` function should first create `foo` and make it **global**, because it has not been declared and it is being assigned to 0 without any var before it. but what really happens differ from my expectation.
`foo` does not become global, it is still local.

Is it true to assume that function's scopes remain after the function execution ends?
Or if not, is it true to say that only **lists of localy declared variables** is saved somewhere?
Ive read about closures, but did not understand them exactly. answers to this question make closures really clearer to me than before. Thx.

Comment: It's not safe to assume that even such lists would be stored somewhere, in some cases it might be a premature optimization. Overall, the function body is executed independently each time the function is called. If you want to use some static properties, place it in the upper scope (or augment the function itself - it's an object, after all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function:

```
aww = function() {
    if(doit) {var foo; doit = false;} else {}
    foo = 0; foo += 1; return foo;
}
```

is interpreted as if it were written like this:

```
aww = function() {
    var foo;
    if(doit) {doit = false;} else {}
    foo = 0; foo += 1; return foo;
}
```

The function will always return 1, because `foo` is always set to `0` and then `1` by the function. The variable declaration is treated as if it occurred at the top of the function.

The reference to `doit` is the part of this that has to do with a closure. Because that variable is external to the function, the function will toggle its value to false the first time it's called, and then won't change it again. It *could* access `doit` and rely on its value remaining the same between calls, unless something else has access to `doit` and makes changes.

The variable `foo`, on the other hand, is a simple local variable to the function. Every call to the function will create a brand new `foo`, and that one will have no relationship to any `foo` that came before it.

Comment: Well said. OP, have a look at javascript variable hoisting for more information about this behavior.

Comment: thanks, learned something but still not get some parts. are you meaning that the scope of a function will be lost after it has been executed? but I see different behavior from closures (which are function calls) like the example [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) at the end of page. and I see that the scope of that function expression still exists and is being used by the inner function `add`. true?

Comment: @TechJS the scope (the closure) is not lost, but `foo` is not part of the closure - it's a local variable. (It *would* be part of a closure if `aww` did something to expose its local context, but it doesn't.)